# Excel return Cell Style in a fromula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel how do I return the Style name applied to a cell as a formula?

When i use the `=CELL("Color",AA11)` (see below) it doesn't return a colour value, it still thinks it is unformatted, none of the other `=Cell()` functions seem to return style info either.

[image: Example]

These are the styles as given  by excel, I've marked a bunch of fields as good, bad or neutral. Ideally I'd like to be able to return 'Good' or 'Bad' etc into a cell.

[image: Styles]

Thanks

Comment: "color" The value 1 if the cell is formatted in color for negative values; otherwise returns 0 (zero). Reference https://support.office.com/en-us/article/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very easy UDF:

```
Function GetStyle(rng As Range)
    GetStyle = rng.Style
End Function
```

Call in your cell `B2` like `=GetStyle(B2)`

**Edit**

It's good to realize a UDF wont recalculate when you are changing the format of a cell!

Comment: Thanks that's great. Bit daft they don't have an easier way to return this as the 'good, 'bad' styles are clearly geared towards being used as highlighting things and people are going to want to return them, a "style" attribute to the cell function would seem like a logical place for it, oh well